# Stop Eclipse from automatically inserting semicolons

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm programming at work in Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse) in Java and something that's bothering me is the IDE automatically inserts semicolons after print statements, where typing

System.out.println(*cursor*

Automatically gets changed to

System.out.println(*cursor*);

I am often looking away at other materials while typing and due to me having already developed good programming habits, I often find print statements in my code that have two closing parenthesis and two semicolons after them because I have the habit of inserting semicolons and parenthesis where they are supposed to go on my own. The auto-parenthesis and auto-quotes don't bother me as much because in most cases, the auto-inserted character can be typed over manually without it inserting a second one, but this behavior is not present for semicolons. Also, the auto-semicolon is not limited to just print statements, they are just where I see it most often.

I am aware of the setting in *Preferences>Java>Editor>Typing>"Automatically insert at correct position">* semicolons and parentheses check boxes. Semicolons checkbox is already unchecked by default and I've already unchecked the parentheses checkbox, but the auto right-parentheses-semicolon behavior persists.

I am also aware of the setting in *Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>"Auto Activation"* settings, where there is a checkbox to *enable auto activation* and a text field for the *Auto activation triggers for Java*. Changing these settings disables the auto-semicolon, but it also disables the popup tooltips, code recommendations, and JavaDocs, which I require.

How can I disable this auto-semicolon behavior without disabling the popup tooltips?